# How do I expand item width in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I did search a bit but all the post I could find is talking about expandable recyclerview which makes its item a bit higher, to show or fold an action bar for example. But that's not what I am looking for unfortunately.

The recycler view I have is a grid, in 3 columns, basically 3 x 3 items in a screen. And by clicking any one of those items I'd like to expand it (better smoothly), not only in height but also in width, to make the clicked item hold almost entire screen (let's say 1 x 1 item).

The transition looks like this: 
https://material.io/guidelines/motion/transforming-material.html#transforming-material-rectangular-transformation, but in this example it is only one item, unlike in recycler view there are usually other items around it.

Is that in any way possible? Any idea is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I use this library on my adapter rows https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout

```
implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
```

Easy to use and well documented.

Also you may like Groupie https://github.com/lisawray/groupie

```
implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.0.3'
```

You can do everything you want with very complex adapters.

Comment: Thanks! But this lib looks like a "vertically expandable + horizontally swipable" one, no? what I am looking for is a "vertically + horizontally expandable", pretty much same with this one: https://material.io/guidelines/motion/transforming-material.html#transforming-material-rectangular-transformation, in the Material Design guideline.